# Configure macOS High Sierra Firewall to expose Docker container running NGinx On Port 80

Tags: networking, macos, firewall, docker

I'm running an Nginx container on a firewall enabled macOS High Sierra machine with the following:

```
docker run -p 80:80 --name nginx nginx
```

Accessing Nginx via the machine's private network IP address works fine from the machine itself, but fails when trying to access it on a different machine on the network.

Things I've tried:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --add  /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/Docker
sudo /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --unblockapp  /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/MacOS/Docker
```

and

```
sudo /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --add /usr/local/bin/vpnkit
sudo /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --unblockapp /usr/local/bin/vpnkit
```

since vpnkit seems to be listening on port 80 with `lsof -i :80`:

*vpnkit                         TCP *:http (LISTEN)*

Additionally, doing an nmap -p 80  shows:

*PORT   STATE     SERVICE*

*80/tcp filtered http*

Comment: Did this ever receive an acceptable answer? I'm facing the same issue.